# Run java program using another program

Tags: java, compilation, cmd

I want to create a Java program through which I can compile and run another program.
I usually know how to compile and run via cmd. Is there any idea to use cmd command in Java program?

Comment: Do you mean compile and run a program on cmd, which in itself will compile and run a second program? And if so, why?

Comment: andrew i'm creating a java project to compile compile and run other java programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. You use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, or [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). For more details, see the java API.